# apache2 - RewriteRule just change the name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a folder with content in it. URL to it: `http://www.example.com/something/`
Is it possible now to rewrite the URL to this: `http://www.example.com/learning/`?

If yes, how?

**Note**: Folder something has some subfolders and a lot of HTML and PHP Files, including CSS and JS stuff.

**Second note:**: I can just edit my `httpd.conf`

**Edit**:
I'm using apache2 and jboss. apache2 just for the proxy and rewrite module. So my jboss application can be reached at this location: `http://www.example.com:1231/something/`.
I just defined that the jboss application ca be reached under port 80 at this url `http://www.example.com/something/`.
Now i wanna do the redirect like above.

Comment: You should edit the question to show what you've already attempted and include any relevant sections of your config.

Comment: That hasn't really helped... Can you not include the config?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/something(.*) http://www.example.com:1234/learning$1 [P]
```

Comment: Isn't working.. maybe because i'm using a proxy rule? and maybe also because i'm not using a absolute path, because i put this in the `<Directory />` in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: I don't think the rules should be in a `<Directory>` directive, they should exist in the `VirtualHost` root.